# Converting a closed contour (array of points) into a solid 3d plane

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, mesh, contour

I have a 2d array of coordinates describing a contour of this image: [image]

```
[[[531  85]]

 [[532  84]]

 [[533  84]]

 ...

 [[528  86]]

 [[529  86]]

 [[530  85]]]
```

How can I transform this contour into a solid plane/mesh that I can work with in CAD?
I tried Pyvista for triangulation, but it couldn't parse my array as input.
I thought this might be an easy problem, but I just cannot figure it out.